# Ошибка отсутствия JS | python requests

Tags: python, парсер, requests

Есть сайт(https://qiwi.com/payment/exchange) с которого нужно спарсить курс валют(использую **bs4**). Проблема в том, что у них стоит проверка на JS, т.е. при попытке зайти на сайт через модуль **requests**, вместо желаемой страницы открывается страница с сообщением об отсутствии JS. Стоит также выделить то, что если открыть код этой страницы в браузере, он выдаст тоже самое предупреждение.

**Мой код:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://qiwi.com/payment/exchange')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

print(soup)
```

Результат выполнения: https://pastebin.com/2Te78gfV

Как решить проблему "отсутствия JS", есть ли какие либо альтернативы(нужен именно курс qiwi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [Selenium WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Не знал про это.